# Is it possible to assign new function to "left swipe" on MIUI11

Tags: android-10, miui

I failed to find the option in settings which will assign different (custom) functionality when I "swipe left" on the homescreen. I want to get rid off news feed and leave just google search if possible. I am using MIUI 11 on the top of Android 10. Maybe this is basic question but I am new to android and I could not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid off the news feed and have only google search enter in application `google` then in the settings of the application ( click on `more` that is in the bottom right corner then `settings` ) enter `general` and turn off `discover`.
If you want to remove the function of left swipe enter in `settings` then in the `home screen` then turn off `google discover`.
There is no option to change `google` app from function left swipe.

Comment: That's it. I found out how to completely disable it, but I was not aware I could leave google search only. Very useful answer for an Android newbie